# Sudden "Overfull \hbox" warning messages

Tags: line-breaking, warnings

(Apologies if this is a duplicate; I didn't see my question among the *many* overfull `\hbox` questions already asked.)

My TeX file had been typsetting without any problems for a few days, when suddenly it started to complain of an overfull `\hbox` at a line that I had not modified since the previous compile. (The output still looks fine to me, for the record.)

The line that causes the problems is

> More precisely, let $\P^N$
> denote the space of all quadrics in a projective space $\P^n$ (so
> $N= {n+2 \choose 2}-1$.)

and the warning message is

> ERROR: ** Overfull \hbox (1.12373pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 164--164
>
> --- TeX said ---
>
> (amsmath)                 on input line 53.
>
> --- HELP ---
>
> Because it couldn't find a good place for a line break, TeX put more
> on this line than it should.

Can anyone diagnose this problem?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) The "Overfull `\hbox` message is not an error, but only a warning; the error is due to `\choose`; with `amsmath` there's the better `\binom{n+2}{2}` instead of `{n+2\choose 2}`.

Comment: Thanks for your help! (I plumped for "error" rather than "warning" because the message I got said "error".) I understand that \choose is sub-optimal, but what I'm really curious about is why such a warning should suddenly appear when LaTeX was compiling the line perfectly happily before. (And, for full disclosure, I felt too lazy to change all the \choose commands to \binom commands.)

Comment: Those messages are probably from your front-end to LaTeX, the style is different. Overfull lines depend on many factors; it's possible that you have modified the paragraph.

Comment: Changing fonts can make lines longer/shorter too. Or a change in style moves the margins.

Comment: We can't track down an overfull box based on one fragment: as egreg says, they depend on many things. We'll need a full example to give more help.